# Can I redistribute node.exe in my commercial Application's Installer?

Tags: licensing, redistribution, software-use

I want to use node.exe and a very simple Javascript that essentially uses only the net module for some functionality in my product. I don't need anything else. I know electron and other frameworks are indeed using the node or may be the V8 engine internally or may be they are just using Chromium Embedded Framework. I do not need to render anything, I just need the most basic functionality that the standalone node.exe alone can handle. Is it is legal to include node.exe in my product's installer? Looking at their License it seems that it should be allowed. But so far I have not seen anyone doing it.

Here is the license: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/LICENSE

What does this requirement really mean?

> rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
>   and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
>   Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>   The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Am I supposed to just include some text file called LICENSE.txt that includes this text and copy it somewhere in the installation folder? Is that it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, yes. Copying the `LICENSE` file should be sufficient. If you really want to cover your bases, you should make this obvious from the GUI. A common practice is to have an "Open Source Attribution" section in your help, with a note in the spirit of "This product uses Node.js, Copyright (c) Joyent, Inc. For full details see `/path/to/myprogram/3rd-parties/nodejs/LICENSE`"

Comment: Thank you very much @Mureinik , that really helps.
BTW in my use case it is a UI less Agent, there is no User Interface at all. Will it be still fine to just include the LICENSE file in the installation folder and mention it again somewhere on the Product  WebSite?

Comment: @dNyaanopaasak If there's no UI you definitely can't present anything there :-) re-distributing the `LICENSE` file is definitely a requirement,  and mentioning it in the website is probably also a good move.

Comment: You could also include a brief mention in the `--version` output if you really want to, but it's probably unnecessary.

Comment: Nice touch @Kevin